# Rounding the solution of NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, rounding

How do I round `x` and `y` solved in the equation to only integer solutions?
I get an error no matter where I put `Integers` or `Round`, for example:

```
NSolve[{x + y == 12, 4 y - 3 x == 4}, {x, y}]
```

In addition, after solving the equation,Why is a previously obtained solution not naturally substituted into the next function written? What should I add?assign the previously obtained solution?

I want to calculate `a`or `ab`, but there are no values in x and y, so the character expressions come out as there are.

```
NSolve[{x + y == 10, y - x == 4}, {x, y}];
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
a=RandomSample[list, x] 
or
ab=Plus[x,y]...etc
```

Comment: Try: `{x, y} /. NSolve[{x + y == 12, 4 y - 3 x == 4}, {x, y}] // Round`. NDSolve returns a solution that needs to be stored.. E.g. sol= NdSolve...

Comment: ...or `soln = NSolve[{x + y == 10, y - x == 4}, {x, y}, Integers]; RandomSample[list, x /. First@soln]`

Comment: For example, when [{x + y == 11, y - x == 4}],in the case of NSolve[{x + y == 11, y - x == 4}, {x, y}, Integers], I could not get an answer. I also want to use not only x but also y in the following equation. y cannot be taken in First.

Comment: @hare, do you want to find only integer solutions or do you want to round the solutions? Obviously, $x + y = 11, y - x = 4$, has no integer solution, because the solution is $x = 7/2, y= 15/2$. But if you want to round these solutions to $x=4, y=8$, then you can use `Round[{x, y}, 1] /. Solve[{x + y == 11, y - x == 4}, {x, y}]`.

Comment: I understood I need to use Round